# GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: android, flutter, geocoding

```
Note: /Users/jouleslabs/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geocoding/GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

Configuration
geocoding: ^2.0.1

Platform:

Android

Answer (score 2):

This library still builds against Android Support libraries and may simply be outdated.
The deprecation is no problem, unless building against API 31, where it finally breaks: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geocoding/issues/87

For more info, enable deprecation warnings in `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore this warning, it has nothing to do on your side. It's telling that the [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) package uses deprecated API.